# Failed to read schema document mule-test.xsd in Mule configuration file

Tags: spring, testing, junit, mule

Below is my test-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
    xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/current/mule-test.xsd ">

...

  <flow name="mock_receiver" doc:name="mock_receiver">

    ...
    <test:component>
        <test:return-data>error_q</test:return-data>
    </test:component>

  </flow>
</mule>
```

Below error shown in Eclipse IDE on line :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/current/mule-test.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'test:component'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/
     schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
```

And getting below error on deploying application to Mule standalone server:

```
ERROR [24 May 2013 01:59:25,186] [WrapperListener_start_runner] (DispatchingLogger:365) - null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'test:component'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. There was 2 files with the name test-config.xml and I was doing changes in the wrong one.